# Not able to see holoviz panel output in local vsCode

Tags: jupyter-notebook, panel, python-3.10, holoviz-panel

```
*import panel as pn
file_input = pn.widgets.FileInput()
display(pn.panel(file_input))*
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXuC7.png)

I also tried adding :
*pn.extension()*

But got the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgZSt.png)

EXPECTING :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRg4F.png)

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Mr. Mark's [setup example](https://gist.github.com/MarcSkovMadsen/156b76e36c00fb30ea4aa627b88a0737) notice you have to have a couple of extra modules installed to ensure Panel works with VsCode, namely `jupyter_bokeh`. There are other guides as well ([official one for example](https://panel.holoviz.org/getting_started/installation.html))